# No application can perform this action, when send email

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text.getText());
            sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email with"));
```

this was my code.

I tried the send mail in emulator. But it shows the no application can perform this action. if anyone knows means tell me

Thanks in advance

Comment: please look into my answer and accept it, if it helped you (I am sure it would)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use [`text/plain`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND)

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
```

Also, the `Intent.ACTION_SEND` is made for sharing, you may want to use `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` to only get the list of e-mail clients, or avoid sharing applications such as Facebook, Twitter, etc.

Comment: if i used the ACTION_SENDTO it will show the text box. but i cant able type any thing in that. @Gorcyn

Comment: the complete text editor is working fine in my android phone. But it is not working in my virtual machine. tell me anyone whats the problem? or i want to run any other low version.

Comment: Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, text.getText());
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email with")); it works partially fine

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: I like this solution best, because Intent.ACTION_SENDTO does not bring up any email apps with many phones.

Answer (score 3):

There's a better approach if you want to send mail: use `Action.SEND_TO`:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:sample@mail.com"));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text.getText());
```

That will narrow down the searchlist.

**NOTE**: Make sure you have set up email account on emulator, else the Email application will not be in the handlers-list, and you'll get exception.

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no application that is registered for handling such kind of intent.

Edit:
Try setting the intent type to "text/plain"

```
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

and/or set [EXTRA_EMAIL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL) to set the content of the email

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, text.getText());
```

Comment: the app is text editor. rest of all the save, save as, search text all of them are working correctly. if i tried to send email the text it shows this error

Comment: Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, text.getText());
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email with")); It will show one text box but i cant able to edit in that....

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything as mentioned in the above comments, if you don't find your solution, Just set an email in the default email in Emulator. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun sendMail(recipient: String, subject: String, message: String)
{
    val mIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    mIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:sample@gmail.com")
    mIntent.type = "text/plain"
    mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf(recipient))
    mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
    mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Choose email client"))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hey !! We received your order :) ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }catch (e:Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry your order could not be sent :( ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

This code works for me, I was facing the same problem,
changing : "val mIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)" to
"val mIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)" solved the problem for me.
Hope my response would help the readers

Answer (score -1):

This generally means that there is no application installed currently, that understands the request you're making.

In this instance I would hazard a guess that there is no email app installed on the emulator? Or possibly that it hasn't been set up.